# Is using epoxy this way on a kitchen sink installation/repair acceptable?

Tags: adhesive, kitchen-sink

I had a new quartz countertop installed, and everything looked very nice. But one day washing the sink I saw that some water was getting between the sink and counter top. I thought, no problem, I'll just get some silicone. But in the process I saw that one corner of the sink had this fiberglass "junction" (my guess is that the screw hole got ripped out and instead of fixing that they just glued the corner using fiberglass). This is a new job, and it has a year warranty, and everything seems to be holding fine (I had actually filled up the whole sink with water while I was doing dishes and it seemed to hold up?). But it seems kinda like a botched job. Is this an acceptable repair/installation? Or should I try to request a more "clean" repair/installation?

Edit: added the "normal" fastener on one of the other corners (this is looking at the bottom just in case that isn't clear)
[image][image]

Comment: Chances are, that repair is stronger than the original technique would've been. That said, I'm not clear what screw hole you're referring to. Whether the repair is satisfactory is really up to you. It wouldn't bother me, but I've made many such impromptu repairs myself over the years.

Comment: I agree also the patch looks bad but how else do you keep the material in place, if there is no cracking of the repair it should be fine, to my eye there is almost double the strength at the repair due to the amount and area covered.

Comment: Quibble:  that is not "fiberglass", but rather epoxy.

Comment: Added a picture of another corner. Yeah.. it's one of those things where it seems to work.. but I'm not sure if I should be satisfied with it.

Comment: @Esteban in your picture I see the metal ring on the one side but where they have their repair - where is it. You have the metal hold in bracket that crosses a ring but not where that repair is .. something is definitely not right. I am guessing the sink was cut to fit or something ..look closely at all 4 mounts and take pictures of each and post if you would like another set of eyes all the way around - but I think something is really odd. On the repair side your picture shows an outline of where I suspect a metal ring part of the sink was..

Comment: Its not stated, but I believe this is an under-mounted sink.  These are installed using 4+ clips holding the sink to the underside of the countertop.   When the installer attaches the sink, they should put a heavy bead of silicone caulk between the sink and the countertop, tighten the clips, and clean up the visible (top) edges.   From the bottom, you will see the edge/rim of the sink and the clips holding it "tight" to the material.  I suspect that the wood shim in epoxy is serving that role here.  The clips can be anchored in slots, or often granite, a plastic anchor epoxied into a hole.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you are having a problem and this unit was installed professionally and has a warranty on it. Call them back out to fix the thing right . If it had screws to retain it and one broke off on installation and now they need to fix it - too bad for them - they should fix it - why should you have to live with a problem or potential problems - you probably worked hard for your money - depends on how much you value what you paid for.

What I am guessing (from my experience) is that there was a mounting screw attached to the sink that held it in place and the screw popped off the sink itself - of course there could have been a metal piece attached to the quartz as well usually with an epoxy.

> What does the other mount side look like a picture of that would
>   make it easier for people to know exactly what you are talking about. There should be at least 2 mounts if not 4.

I would call them back and say hey I have a problem and I thought to go fix it myself but this is what I found .. I want the thing fixed and fixed right. Where fixed right means you should not have a problem with it - especially with in one year!

**EDIT 11/15/2017** 
Using your posted picture I wanted to outline something I noticed .. notice the ring outline near the repair - in your second photo with a correct mount shown you can see the metal ring - in the first photo you posted you see an outline where something was but it is gone - I am thinking the fish docks are wafting some air - smells fishy to me.

[image: Underside repaired mount]

Comment: Added a pic of the other side, yeah it's a total of four fasteners (where one is that epoxy job). What I wasn't sure if that was "the professional repair", since I have zero experience on this.. so would it be reasonable to say that this isn't a proper repair?

Comment: @Esteban I would not call it proper; it looks exactly as I had thought - they tightened too much (because sink area was leaking??) and broke it off of the quartz.The screw might have been fastened to the quartz with an epoxy of some sort or perhaps it was drilled in. Me personally I don't think I would accept it especially with water leaking down through the sink area to the cabinet another reason to have them to do it right. Just My opinion.

Comment: This is not the best fixup, but my criteria would be; what does it look like up top. Is the epoxy visible?  Is the countertop/sink joint clean, smoooth, and the edge properly aligned all the way around.  And if it's leaking, they should have caulked better.   Also, if you put pressure on the sink in the patched corner, does it sag and open the caulk joint?